# Consultar diferentes valores de un array pero que tienen una misma llave

Tags: php, array

Tengo un problema, estoy intentando recuperar los valores de un array que tienen la misma key, por ejemplo:

En el siguiente arreglo tengo dos correos iguales pero con diferente información:

```
Array ( [mensaje] => Array ( [correo] => prueba@outlook.com 
                             [servicio] => CFE 
                             [producto] => CFE 
                             [saldo] => 98 ) ) 
Array ( [mensaje] => Array ( [correo] => prueba@outlook.com 
                             [servicio] => Dish 
                             [producto] => Dish 
                             [saldo] => 527.0 ) ) 
Array ( [mensaje] => Array ( [correo] => tyu@outlook.com 
                             [servicio] => Dish 
                             [producto] => Dish 
                             [saldo] => 527.0 ) )
```

Mi intencion es poder imprimir en una sola linea los servicios y el saldo que estan registrados con el mismo correo, por ejemplo:

Salida que espero poder formar:

> El correo electronico prueba@outlook.com tiene dos cuentas pendientes
> una es CFE con saldo de 98 y otra es Dish con saldo de 527.0

La forma en la que cree ese array es la siguiente:

```
$arregloDatosCorreo [] = (['mensaje' => array('correo' => $arrCorreos[0]['email'],
                                              'servicio' => $servicioProntoPago,
                                              'producto' => $productoProntoPago,
                                              'saldo' => $saldo)
                          ]);
```

Luego lo recorro con un foreach para poder mostrar el arreglo de mensaje

```
foreach ($arregloDatosCorreo as $row) {
   # Aqui podremos imprimir el arreglo de mensajes -> $row['mensaje'];
   print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Hola Enrique. No entiendo los datos que muestras. ¿Son varios arrays por separado, es un sólo array con sub-arrays dentro? No me cuadra. pon la estructura exacta o aclara el contexto.

Comment: @A.Cedano era un unico array con otros array en su interior pero mi problema era que no podia como agrupar los datos por ejemplo por el correo para que no se repitiera ese campo, pero ya lo resolvi, queria subir la respuesta pero aun no me deja hacerlo